# Android - Native code trigger a SIGILL only on emulator

Tags: android, native-code, fault

My app is triggering a SIGILL fault only when i run it on the emulator. The app is using ActionBarSherlock and the minimum SDK target is API level 8. The fault is triggered when native code is executed (the rest of the app, written in Java, seems to work). I have tried a number of different emulator setup without success. There is no specific code that is faulting. If i comment the function that is faulting, the SIGILL is triggered by some other function at some other point. I use the macro LOGI to write things on the console and the native-code functions are called properly. I have absolutely no idea of what is happening. The app is working perfectly on two different phones (an armv6 rev 5 running android 2.3.4 and an armv7 rev 9 running android 4.0.3). The native code is a library that i have written and tested on my Windows desktop system, and it is working without problems.
Help!

Android.mk

> ```
> OCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)    
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)    
> #LOCAL_CFLAGS     := -DANDROID_NDK -Wno-psabi
> LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += png++/ 
> LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += libpng/
> LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += zlib/
> LOCAL_MODULE    := mylib
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := /* a list of .cpp files... */
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(wildcard ./*.c)
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(wildcard ./zlib/*.c)
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(wildcard ./libpng/*.c)
> LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
> LOCAL_LDLIBS += -ljnigraphics
> LOCAL_CFLAGS += -marm -march=armv6 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -fpermissive -fwrapv -O2 -fexceptions    
> include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
> ```

Application.mk

> ```
> APP_STL := gnustl_static
> APP_OPTIM := release
> APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti
> ```

Comment: show us at least Android.mk + Application.mk ... and emulator ... are you using Intel x86 or Arm ABI ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I gave up trying on emulator; I think it's something related to ARMv6 support on Android emulator. As mine works on the device too, I no longer care about this issue.